# Selecting distinct 5 columns combination in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, distinct-values

I have a mysql table that looks like this: Col 1 is UNIQUE.

```
1   value1    value2    0    2
2   value1    value2    1    3
3   value3    value4    3    2
4   value4    value5    4    1
5   value3    value4    3    1
```

I need a query to select all the rows with distinct column 1 and 2, for example the output I want for this example will look like this:

```
1   value1    value2    0    2
3   value3    value4    3    2
4   value4    value5    4    1
```

I need distinct col 1 and 2 but altogether all columns combination will be distinct always. I want to display distinct col 1,2 and 3 without col 2,3 repeating.

I've found a few samples on how to do it but they all select distinct on each column individually. I tried many stackoverflow answers too. But my question is different.

Comment: I think you want col2 and col3 to be distinct based on your data.  You should fix the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that performs well is a correlate subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col1 = (select min(t2.col1)
                from t t2
                where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 = t.col3
               );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `(col2, col3, col1)`.

I strongly advise having a primary key on all tables, but if you did not have one, then `row_number()` would be the way to go:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col2, col3 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This incurs a tad more overhead because row numbers need to be assigned to all rows before they are filtered for only first one.

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved by using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col1) AS rn
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE rn=1
```